# How would I refactor this C code to get rid of repetition

Tags: c, refactoring

I am working on writing a driver for a microcontroller to interface with a sensors. The sensor that I am using is the MAG3110. I have written a driver that can control everything on the sensor but there is a lot of code repetition. Three quarters of the functions are in the forms that follow:

```
 uint8_t ReadWhoAmI(uint8_t *readPtr)
 { 
    return MagReadByte(WHO_AM_I, readPtr);
 }
```

or

```
uint8_t SetSingleMeasurmentMode()
{
    uint8_t currentReg1Flags;
    ReadCtrlReg1(&currentReg1Flags);

    currentReg1Flags &= 0xFC; 
    currentReg1Flags |= CTRL_REG1_SINGLE_MEASURMENT; 

    return WriteCtrlReg1(currentReg1Flags);
}
```

How could these functions be generalized? I know in functional programming I would simply parameterize the function, but I don't know how I could apply a similar concept in C.

Comment: well, *what* is repeated and what is not? which parts of the functions can change and which parts should stay intact?

Comment: Could you not make `ReadCtrlReg1()` return the value instead of requiring the variable passed by reference?  I agree with The Paramagnetic Croissant: it is not clear from the two samples that there is any repetition.  You'd need to show at least two instances of each function pattern for people to have a chance of working out how to help very much.  For example, how many `ReadCtrlRegX()` functions are there? (Incidentally, in normal English, 'measurement' contains 3 e's.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a generalized version of `SetSingleMeasurmentMode` by using:

```
uint8_t SetSingleMeasurmentModeGen(void (*ReadFunction)(uint8_t*),
                                   void (*WriteFunction)(uint8_t))
{
    uint8_t currentReg1Flags;
    ReadFunction(&currentReg1Flags);

    // Assuming this logic remains same.
    currentReg1Flags &= 0xFC; 
    currentReg1Flags |= CTRL_REG1_SINGLE_MEASURMENT; 

    return WriteFunction(currentReg1Flags);
}
```

and using:

```
uint8_t SetSingleMeasurmentMode()
{
    return SetSingleMeasurmentModeGen(ReadCtrlReg1, WriteCtrlReg1);
}
```

If the logic to change the value of the flag does not remain same, you need to pass another function.

```
uint8_t SetSingleMeasurmentModeGen(void (*ReadFunction)(uint8_t*),
                                   uint8_t (*TransformFlag)(uint8_t),
                                   void (*WriteFunction)(uint8_t))
{
    uint8_t currentReg1Flags;
    ReadFunction(&currentReg1Flags);    
    return WriteFunction(TransformFlag(currentReg1Flags));
}

uint8_t TransformFlag1(uint8_t flag)
{
    flag &= 0xFC; 
    flag |= CTRL_REG1_SINGLE_MEASURMENT; 
    return flag;
}

uint8_t SetSingleMeasurmentMode()
{
    return SetSingleMeasurmentModeGen(ReadCtrlReg1, TransformFlag1, WriteCtrlReg1);
}
```